# pandas: iterating over DataFrame index with loc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I can't seem to find the reasoning behind the behaviour of .loc. I know it is label based, so if I iterate over Index object the following minimal example should work. But it doesn't. I googled of course but I need additional explanation from someone who has already got a grip on indexing.

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dict_weekday = {1: 'MON', 2: 'TUE', 3: 'WED', 4: 'THU', 5: 'FRI', 6: 'SAT', 7: 'SUN'}
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2014, 1, 15), freq='D'),   columns=['Date'])
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: dict_weekday[x.isoweekday()])

for idx in df.index:
    print df.loc[idx, 'Weekday']
```

Comment: The function is working correctly, you will find that your Weekday column is in fact a timestamp which is why it looks funny.

Comment: Why is it a timestamp. dict_weekday has strings for values. By the way, if I use .ix instead of .loc it work fine, but I think it should also work the same with .loc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not in `df.loc`; 
`df.loc[idx, 'Weekday']` is just returning a Series. 
The surprising behavior is due to the way `pd.Series` tries to cast datetime-like values to Timestamps.

```
df.loc[0, 'Weekday']
```

forms the Series

```
pd.Series(np.array([pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), 'WED'], dtype=object))
```

When `pd.Series(...)` is called, it [tries to cast the data](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L2623) to an appropriate dtype.

If you trace through the code, you'll find that it eventually arrives at [these lines in pandas.core.common._possibly_infer_to_datetimelike](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/common.py#L1710):

```
sample = v[:min(3,len(v))]
inferred_type = lib.infer_dtype(sample)
```

which is inspecting the first few elements of the data and trying to infer the dtype.
When one of the values is a pd.Timestamp, Pandas checks to see if all the data can be cast as Timestamps. Indeed, `'Wed'` can be cast to pd.Timestamp:

```
In [138]: pd.Timestamp('Wed')
Out[138]: Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00')
```

This is the root of the problem, which results in `pd.Series` returning 
two Timestamps instead of a Timestamp and a string:

```
In [139]: pd.Series(np.array([pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), 'WED'], dtype=object))
Out[139]: 
0   2014-01-01
1   2014-12-17
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and thus this returns

```
In [140]: df.loc[0, 'Weekday']
Out[140]: Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00')
```

instead of `'Wed'`.

---

**Alternative: select the Series `df['Weekday']` first**:

There are many workarounds; EdChum shows that adding a non-datelike (integer) value to the sample can prevent pd.Series from casting all the values to Timestamps.

Alternatively, you could access `df['Weekdays']`  *before* using `.loc`:

```
for idx in df.index:
    print df['Weekday'].loc[idx]
```

---

**Alternative: `df.loc[[idx], 'Weekday']`**:

Another alternative is

```
for idx in df.index:
    print df.loc[[idx], 'Weekday'].item()
```

`df.loc[[idx], 'Weekday']`  first selects *the DataFrame* `df.loc[[idx]]`. For example, when `idx` equals `0`,

```
In [10]: df.loc[[0]]
Out[10]: 
        Date Weekday
0 2014-01-01     WED
```

whereas `df.loc[0]` returns the Series:

```
In [11]: df.loc[0]
Out[11]: 
Date      2014-01-01
Weekday   2014-12-17
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Series tries to cast the values to a single useful dtype. DataFrames can have a different dtype for each column. So the Timestamp in the `Date` column does not affect the dtype of the value in the `Weekday` column.

So the problem was avoided by using an index selector which returns a DataFrame.

---

**Alternative: use integers for Weekday**

Yet another alternative is to store the isoweekday integer in `Weekday`, and convert to strings only at the end when you print:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dict_weekday = {1: 'MON', 2: 'TUE', 3: 'WED', 4: 'THU', 5: 'FRI', 6: 'SAT', 7: 'SUN'}
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2014, 1, 15), freq='D'),   columns=['Date'])
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday+1   # add 1 for isoweekday

for idx in df.index:
    print dict_weekday[df.loc[idx, 'Weekday']]
```

---

**Alternative: use `df.ix`**:

`df.loc` is a `_LocIndexer`, whereas `df.ix` is a `_IXIndexer`. They have
different `__getitem__` methods. If you step through the code (for example, using pdb) you'll find that [`df.ix` calls `df.getvalue`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L64):

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if type(key) is tuple:
        try:
            values = self.obj.get_value(*key)
```

and the DataFrame method `df.get_value` succeeds in returning `'WED'`:

```
In [14]: df.get_value(0, 'Weekday')
Out[14]: 'WED'
```

This is why `df.ix` is another alternative that works here.

Comment: hello unutbu, thanks for your reply. If I understand you correctly this is the way how .loc should work. What is different with the .ix? Also why would df.loc[[idx], 'Weekday'].item() work? What does this list do? I can understand that df.loc[0] or df.loc['Weekday'] return s Series, but I thought that df.loc[0, 'Weekday'] simply returns an element of a DataFrame. Can you elaborate on some of this. I will check your answer as correct since you gave a detailed explanation but still please try to give answers to the above as well. Thanks.

Comment: I added some comments on how `df.ix` and `df.loc[[idx], ...]` work. Unfortunately, I don't understand the indexers well enough to give you high-level heuristic rules for how they work in plain English. I can only trace through the code (using pdb) and find out at a micro-level why the right or wrong value is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug to me, for reference I am using python 3.3.5 64-bit, pandas 0.15.1 and numpy 1.9.1:

Your code shows that although it is printing as strings the dtype is a timestamp:

```
In [56]:

df.iloc[0]['Weekday']
Out[56]:
Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00')
```

If I do the following then it stays as a string:

```
In [58]:

df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: dict_weekday[x.isoweekday()])
df['WeekdayInt'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.isoweekday())
df.iloc[0]['Weekday']
Out[58]:
'WED'
```

The above is odd as all I did was add a second column.

Similarly if I create a column to store the int day value and then perform the apply then it works also:

```
In [60]:

df['WeekdayInt'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.isoweekday())
df['Weekday'] = df['WeekdayInt'].apply(lambda x: dict_weekday[x])
df.iloc[0]['Weekday']
Out[60]:
'WED'
```

It looks like the dtype is somehow persisting or not being assigned correctly if it's the first column appended.

Comment: @user3176500 that I don't know, `ix` first tries label based and then integer for based, for your info `iloc` also shows this error so it's puzzling why `ix` works

Comment: Hmm, is it just me or is this really not a big issue? One more question: Can I use for instance df.loc[idx+1, col_tag]. Will the sum be handled first calculating a new row index or will the row index actually be 'idx+1'. Still the two fundamental questions remain: why the above case does not work and why it works if .ix is used? Hopefully someone of the pandas developers sees this

Comment: EdChum, can you try 0.15.2 version and report back?

Comment: This still happens in 0.15.2, I think it's pretty serious IMO