# Pandas why index prohibits some operation on dataframe (like loc results in IndexingError:)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

There are similar issues asked about (like [pandas: iterating over DataFrame index with loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501694/pandas-iterating-over-dataframe-index-with-loc)) but I could not find mine. I just do not understand why in `pandas` many functionality stops working when `index` is added to `dataframe`. Like just now I have `dataframe` `d1` and can do below to add new column:

```
df4 = df1
df4.loc[df1.crash_type_name == 'pedestrian','Pedestrian_type'] = 1
```

But the same fails for `df2` - same one but index added with `df2 = df1.set_index('date_time')`.

The error

> IndexingError: (0        False 1        False ....

I know the workaround is to `reset_index()` and then to recreate it back, but what is the logic behind `index` prohibiting certain operations on `dataframe`?

Comment: `pandas` aligns on index when you slice it with a boolean Series. Once you change the `Index` the alignment no longer works. In this case, you can still slice with the array, `(df1.crash_type_name == 'pedestrian').to_numpy()` but now there is no guarantee of alignment, so it's prone to errors.

Comment: @ALollz, but original `df1` also shows index - default 0-1-2-etc (from reset_index() = "This resets the index to the default integer index". Why it works with default, but not with other column?

Comment: Because your original `DataFrame` likely also has a `RangeIndex`, so when you `reset_index` they will align. But again, this alignment is now only accidental and if there are intermediate steps that shuffle rows, this can lead to errors.